# Is the return value of this function going directly to the front-end?

Tags: python-3.x, cherrypy

I found this piece of a very useful python script for processing cherrypy server:

```
def uses_json(func):

    @functools.wraps(func)
    @cherrypy.tools.accept(media="application/json")
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

        cherrypy.serving.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json"

        kwargs = dict(kwargs)

        try:
            body = cherrypy.request.body.read()
            kwargs.update(json.loads(body))
        except TypeError:
            pass

        return json.dumps(func(*args, **kwargs)).encode('utf8')

    return wrapper
```

My question is for the line that returns the `json.dumps` result. Is this result going directly back to the front-end? Or it will be going somewhere inside cherrypy? I couldn't find this in official documentation.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @mkrieger1 nothing extradinory. just as the tutorial indicated, whatever is supposed to happen did happen.